# Excel Power Query eof error

Tags: sql, excel, eof

I am trying to get Excel to combine several a particular row/record in several different spreadsheets into one giant table using PowerQuery. I used the step by step function to create the basic code then try to wrap the function so that Excel will keep going back to the same directory, go into the file select the row required and append it to the table I am creating. But keep getting an error:

> "token Eof expected" error.

What am I missing?

```
let GetFiles=("Z:Accreditation_CSV,MAC_Analysis) =>
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(("(Z,Accreditation_CSV,MAC_Analysis)),
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(("(Z,Accreditation_CSV,MAC_Analysis)),
{{Formattting, specs}}

in GetFiles

Exit Funciton
```

Comment: Any help offered will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Provide the code sample or anything that could make your question easier to understand!!!

Answer (score -1):

Misspelled Function

```
let GetFiles=("Z:Accreditation_CSV,MAC_Analysis) =>
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(("(Z,Accreditation_CSV,MAC_Analysis)),
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(("(Z,Accreditation_CSV,MAC_Analysis)),
{{Formattting, specs}}

in GetFiles

Exit Funciton 


                 .
```

Comment: How does this resolve the issue when misspelt in the answer too?

Comment: It would help if you explained this answer further.